# SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed on PHP yii2 framework

Tags: php, ssl, composer-php, ssl-certificate, yii2-advanced-app

I am using PHP Yii2 framework and my local server is MAMP Pro 4 on MAC OS. My php version was 5.5 and I updated it from system path according to this tutorial(https://gist.github.com/irazasyed/5987693 [instruction on how to change php version][1]). After updating version, I have tried to download widgets from composer, however when I typed `composer update` it shows following errors:

```
The "https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/jquery" file could not be 

downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

I believe this is a error of updating php version from system path because when I return to my old php 5.5 version my composer worked fine!
 Many thanks for your attention!

Comment: Sorry just got here. Did you found anything? @mr-sanatbek